# Why does pandas need to reshape my boolean index, and how can I fix it to avoid the warning?

Tags: python, pandas

### Background

I've got two DataFrames of timestamped-ids (the index is the id). I want to get all of the ids where the timestamps differ by, say, 5 minutes.

### Code

```py
time_delta = abs(df2.time - df1.time).dt.total_seconds()
ids_out_of_range = df1[time_delta > 300].index
```

*This gives me the ids I want, so it is working code.*

### Problem

Like many, I face this warning:

```
file.py:33: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  ids_out_of_range = df1[time_delta > 300].index
```

Most explanations center on the "length" of the index differing from the "length" of the dataframe. But:

```
+(Pdb) time_delta.shape
(176,)
+(Pdb) df1.shape
(176, 1)
+(Pdb) sorted(time_delta.index.values.tolist()) == sorted(df1.index.values.tolist())
True
```

The shapes are the same, except that one is a Series and the other is a DataFrame. The indices (appear) to be the same; perhaps the ordering is the issue? They did not compare equal without `sorted`.

(I've tried wrapping `time_delta` in a DataFrame, to no avail.)

Long-term, I would like this warning to go away (and not with `2>/dev/null`, thank you). It's visual clutter in the output of my script, and, well, it is a warning—so theoretically I should pay attention to it.

### Question

1. What am I doing "wrong" that I get this warning, since the sizes seem to be right?
2. How do I fix (1) so I can avoid this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixed my issue:

```
df1.sort_index(inplace=True)
df2.sort_index(inplace=True)
time_delta.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

This allowed the indices to align perfectly, so they must have not been in the same order with respect to each other.

Answer (score 0):

1. The warning is saying that your time_delta index is different from df index.
   But when I tried to reproduce the warning, it didn't show up. I'm using pandas 0.25.1. So if you are using a different version, there might be a warning.
2. Please refer to this page for [suppressing warnings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings)

Comment: I don't want to suppress the warning; I want to write the code correctly so it disappears. I'm using 0.25.3, but I don't think that should be the major difference. When I googled the text, it seemed relatively common. At any rate, the indices have the same length. If you know an easy way to check the values, I'll do it. But I really think they're equal, hence my confusion

Comment: @D.BenKnoble try print out time_delta.index and df1.index, see if they are the same?

Comment: See my update/answer—it was a sorting issue. I really can't believe it was that simple, that's been hours of time /eyeroll. PS: printing was a non-starter—I can't eyeball 176 values for similarity, esp. not when each one is a 10-digit number

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Of course. I just want to suggest to check the index for all similar scenarios. Usually,  whenever do row-wise calculation, the id should be sorted.